# Returning string from OpenLayers.Format.WKT write?

Tags: openlayers-2, well-known-text

How to return a string from OpenLayers.Format.WKT write

```
this.innerHTML = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().write(
    layer.selectedFeatures[0]
);
```

my full code is like this please suggest me...

```
//OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

var wps = "http:",
    capabilities, // the capabilities, read by Format.WPSCapabilities::read
    process; // the process description from Format.WPSDescribeProcess::read

// get some capabilities
getCapabilities();

// create the UI
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Scratchpad");
var toolbar = new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(layer);
toolbar.addControls([new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(layer, {
    title: "Select feature"
})]);
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    controls: [
        toolbar,
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanPanel()
    ],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "OSM", "",
            {layers: "openstreetmap", format: "image/png"}
        ), layer
    ]
});
map.zoomToMaxExtent();

// add behavior to html elements
document.getElementById("processes").onchange = describeProcess;

// using OpenLayers.Format.WPSCapabilities to read the capabilities
function getCapabilities() {
    OpenLayers.Request.GET({
        url: wps,
        params: {
            "SERVICE": "WPS",
            "REQUEST": "GetCapabilities"
        },
        success: function(response){
            capabilities = new OpenLayers.Format.WPSCapabilities().read(
                response.responseText
            );
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("processes");
            var offerings = capabilities.processOfferings, option;
            // populate the dropdown
            for (var p in offerings) {
                option = document.createElement("option");
                option.innerHTML = offerings[p].identifier;
                option.value = p;
                dropdown.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
    });
}

// using OpenLayers.Format.WPSDescribeProcess to get information about a
// process
function describeProcess() {
    var selection = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    OpenLayers.Request.GET({
        url: wps,
        params: {
            "SERVICE": "WPS",
            "REQUEST": "DescribeProcess",
            "VERSION": capabilities.version,
            "IDENTIFIER": selection
        },
        success: function(response) {
            process = new OpenLayers.Format.WPSDescribeProcess().read(
                response.responseText
            ).processDescriptions[selection];
            buildForm();
        }
    });
}

// dynamically create a form from the process description
function buildForm() {
    document.getElementById("abstract").innerHTML = process["abstract"];
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "<h3>Input:</h3>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

    var inputs = process.dataInputs, supported = true,
        sld = "text/xml; subtype=sld/1.0.0",
        input;
        //var change=inputs.innerHTML.toFixed(2);
    for (var i=0,ii=inputs.length; i<ii; ++i) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        input = inputs[i];
        if (input.complexData) {
        //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in complexdata !!");
            var formats = input.complexData.supported.formats;
            if (formats["application/wkt"]) {
            //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in app/wkt!!");
                addWKTInput(input);
            } else if (formats["text/xml; subtype=
-collection/1.0"]) {
            //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in text/xml!!");
                addCollectionInput(input);
            } else if (formats["image/tiff"]) {

               // addRasterInput(input);
                //alert(truncator(5.1231231, 1));
                //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in image/tiff!!");
                addRasterInput(truncator(input,2));
            } else if (formats[sld]) {
            //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in formatssld!!");
                addXMLInput(input, sld);
            } else {
                supported = false;
            }
        } else if (input.boundingBoxData) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box in bounding box!!");
             // var change=input.innerHTML.toFixed(2);
            addBoundingBoxInput(input);
        } else if (input.literalData) {
        //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in literal box!!");
            addLiteralInput(input);
        } else {
            supported = false;
        }
        if (input.minOccurs > 0) {
        //alert("Hello! I am an alert box in minoccurs box!!");
            document.getElementById("input").appendChild(document.createTextNode("* "));
        }
    }

    if (supported) {
        var executeButton = document.createElement("button");
        executeButton.innerHTML = "Execute";
        document.getElementById("input").appendChild(executeButton);
        executeButton.onclick = execute;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = '<span class="notsupported">' +
            "Sorry, the WPS builder does not support the selected process." +
            "</span>";
    }
}

// helper function to dynamically create a textarea for geometry (WKT) data
// input
function addWKTInput(input, previousSibling) {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box in dynamically create a textarea for geometry data input!!");
    var name = input.identifier;
    var container = document.getElementById("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label["for"] = name;
    label.title = input["abstract"];
    label.innerHTML = name + " (select feature, then click field):";
    previousSibling && previousSibling.nextSibling ?
        container.insertBefore(label, previousSibling.nextSibling) :
        container.appendChild(label);
    var field = document.createElement("textarea");
    field.onclick = function () {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box in onclick!!");
        if (layer.selectedFeatures.length) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box in selected features function for geometry data input writing!!");
            this.innerHTML = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().write(

                //layer.selectedFeatures[0]
                //layer.selectedFeatures[0]
                //name.length();
                //alert(trun.toFixed(2));
                //layer.selectedFeatures[0]
                layer.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.toString()

            );
        }
        createCopy(input, this, addWKTInput);
    };
    field.onblur = function() {
        input.data = field.value ? {
            complexData: {
                mimeType: "application/wkt",
                value: this.value
            }
        } : undefined;
    };
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    field.id = name;
    previousSibling && previousSibling.nextSibling ?
        container.insertBefore(field, previousSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling) :
        container.appendChild(field);
}

// helper function for xml input
function addXMLInput(input, type) {
    var name = input.identifier;
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    field.value = name + " (" + type + ")";
    field.onblur = function() {
        input.data = field.value ? {
            complexData: {
                mimeType: type,
                value: this.value
            }
        } : undefined;
    };
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(field);
}

// helper function to dynamically create a  collection reference input
function addCollectionInput(input) {
    var name = input.identifier;
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    field.value = name + " (layer on demo server)";
    addValueHandlers(field, function() {
        input.reference = field.value ? {
            mimeType: "text/xml; subtype=-collection/1.0",
            href: "http://",
            method: "POST",
            body: {
                : {
                    version: "1.0.0",
                    outputFormat: "GML2",
                    featureType: field.value
                }
            }
        } : undefined;
    });
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(field);
}

// helper function to dynamically create a raster (GeoTIFF) url input
function addRasterInput(input) {
    var name = input.identifier;
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    var url = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    field.value = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")+1) + "data/tazdem.tiff";
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(field);
    (field.onblur = function() {
        input.reference = {
            mimeType: "image/tiff",
            href: field.value,
            method: "GET"
        };
    })();
}

// helper function to dynamically create a bounding box input
function addBoundingBoxInput(input) {
    var name = input.identifier;
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    field.value = "left,bottom,right,top (EPSG:4326)";
    document.getElementById("input").appendChild(field);
    addValueHandlers(field, function() {
        input.boundingBoxData = {
            projection: "EPSG:4326",
            bounds: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString(field.value)
        };
    });
}

// helper function to create a literal input textfield or dropdown
function addLiteralInput(input, previousSibling) {
    var name = input.identifier;
    var container = document.getElementById("input");
    var anyValue = input.literalData.anyValue;
    // anyValue means textfield, otherwise we create a dropdown
    var field = document.createElement(anyValue ? "input" : "select");
    field.id = name;
    field.title = input["abstract"];
    previousSibling && previousSibling.nextSibling ?
        container.insertBefore(field, previousSibling.nextSibling) :
        container.appendChild(field);
    if (anyValue) {
        var dataType = input.literalData.dataType;
        field.value = name + (dataType ? " (" + dataType + ")" : "");
        addValueHandlers(field, function() {
            input.data = field.value ? {
                literalData: {
                    value: field.value
                }
            } : undefined;
            createCopy(input, field, addLiteralInput);
        });
    } else {
        var option;
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = name;
        field.appendChild(option);
        for (var v in input.literalData.allowedValues) {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = v;
            option.innerHTML = v;
            field.appendChild(option);
        }
        field.onchange = function() {
            createCopy(input, field, addLiteralInput);
            input.data = this.selectedIndex ? {
                literalData: {
                    value: this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
                }
            } : undefined;
        };
    }
}

// if maxOccurs is > 1, this will add a copy of the field
function createCopy(input, field, fn) {
    if (input.maxOccurs && input.maxOccurs > 1 && !field.userSelected) {
        // add another copy of the field - we don't check maxOccurs
        field.userSelected = true;
        var newInput = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, input);
        // we recognize copies by the occurrence property
        newInput.occurrence = (input.occurrence || 0) + 1;
        process.dataInputs.push(newInput);
        fn(newInput, field);
    }
}

// helper function for adding events to form fields
function addValueHandlers(field, onblur) {
    field.onclick = function() {
        if (!this.initialValue) {
            this.initialValue = this.value;
            this.value = "";
        }
    };
    field.onblur = function() {
        if (!this.value) {
            this.value = this.initialValue;
            delete this.initialValue;
        }
        onblur.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

// execute the process
function execute() {
    var output = process.processOutputs[0];
    var input;
    // remove occurrences that the user has not filled out
    for (var i=process.dataInputs.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        input = process.dataInputs[i];
        if ((input.minOccurs === 0 || input.occurrence) && !input.data && !input.reference) {
            OpenLayers.Util.removeItem(process.dataInputs, input);
        }
    }
    process.responseForm = {
        rawDataOutput: {
            identifier: output.identifier
        }
    };
    if (output.complexOutput && output.complexOutput.supported.formats["application/wkt"]) {
        process.responseForm.rawDataOutput.mimeType = "application/wkt";
    }
    OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: wps,
        data: new OpenLayers.Format.WPSExecute().write(process),
        success: showOutput
    });
}

// add the process's output to the page
function showOutput(response) {
    var result = document.getElementById("output");
    result.innerHTML = "<h3>Output:</h3>";
    var features;
    var contentType = response.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    if (contentType == "application/wkt") {
        features = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read(response.responseText);
    } else if (contentType == "text/xml; subtype=-collection/1.0") {
        features = new OpenLayers.Format.T.v1_0_0().read(response.responseText);
    }
    if (features && (features instanceof OpenLayers.Feature.Vector || features.length)) {
        layer.addFeatures(features);
        result.innerHTML += "The result should also be visible on the map.";
    }
    result.innerHTML += "<textarea>" + response.responseText + "</textarea>";
}
```

Comment: Please explain more what you want to do.

If you mean you want to display the WKT for the currently selected feature in OpenLayers, then the "Vector formats" example of OpenLayers has the functionality you need: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

Comment: When asking a Question remember that the title is intended to be a summary of the Question body, and the latter should contain ALL details relevant to the Question.

Comment: By "explain" i did not mean "paste the full code", but a written text describing your problem in english text.
You could, for example, try to tell us what in the vector formats example did not work for you.

Comment: when i try to append the follwing to my code its not giving any output i don't layer.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.toString()

Comment: how to get the return value from the if (layer.selectedFeatures.length) {
 this.innerHTML = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().write(
                      layer.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.toString()
    
            );
        }

Comment: POLYGON((-95.343754291534 47.906248569489, -77.062504291534 52.828123569489, -94.640629291534 68.999998569489, -112.21875429153 64.078123569489, -95.343754291534 47.906248569489)) this selected feature should be in the form of POLYGON((-95.34 47.90, -77.06 52.82, -94.64 68.99, -112.21 64.07, -95.34 47.90))

Comment: i am also getting the selected features dimensions but i need turncated formate of it

Comment: how to split that selected feature

Answer (score 1):

```
WKT = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
this.innerHTML = WKT.write(layer.selectedFeatures[0]);
```

Comment: Your Answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content - are you able to expand upon it with a little more detail about how you think this answers the Question?

Comment: i need to display the value in that layer.selectFeatues[] string after that slice the values of the string POLYGON((77.34375 54.345677989,74.123434444 29.3452334,136.456 24.6789000)) then truncate the individual values or rounding should be performed on that values

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. I'd suggest to store the string in a variable. then you can use normal javascript to slice, truncate and rounding.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get WKT just by using

```
layer.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.toString();
```

Comment: i changed but i am not getting dynamiclly generated string value to my text field

Comment: in my wps builder on click i am supposed to get that dynamic values list ...

Comment: in my map i will select one feature based on that it like JTS:buffer and i will select feature on click i will get that feature in my text field like POLYGON((77.34375 54.345677989,74.123434444 29.3452334,136.456 24.6789000))

Comment: i need to display the value in that layer.selectFeatues[] string after that slice the values of the string POLYGON((77.34375 54.345677989,74.123434444 29.3452334,136.456 24.6789000)) then truncate the individual values or rounding should be performed on that values –